# Trying to create view in MYSQL WORKBENCH but there is a 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my code:

```
    create or replace view 'shahargenerals' as
(
Select g.idgeneral , g.namegeneral, g.lastnamegeneral
From    combinesoli_gen_tool com,
        general g,
        solider s
Where   g.friendlygrade > 5
And g.idgeneral = com.idgeneral
And s.trainingtoolsolider = "sahar 5"
And g.kabageneral = (select max(kabageneral)
                    From general)
Group by (com.idsolider)
Having count(com.idsolider)>30
);
```

and the error is:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'replace view 'shahargenerals' as ( Select g.idgeneral , g.namegeneral, g.lastna' at line 1
```

but i dont get why. This code (without the first line of the above code) works fine:

```
Select g.idgeneral , g.namegeneral, g.lastnamegeneral
From    combinesoli_gen_tool com,
        general g,
        solider s
Where   g.friendlygrade > 5
And g.idgeneral = com.idgeneral
And s.trainingtoolsolider = "sahar 5"
And g.kabageneral = (select max(kabageneral)
                    From general)
Group by (com.idsolider)
Having count(com.idsolider)>30
```

Comment: I think the problem is the surrounding parenthesis. What is the output of `SHOW CREATE VIEW shahargenerals;`?

Comment: Don't put the view name in single quotes.

Comment: @EternalHour Parentheses work OK for me.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: i have already tryed it with/without quotes and it doesnt work.
EternalHour there is no output cause there is an error, what do u mean?

@Barmar im using worbench 6.3 ce

Comment: _Probably not relevant to your issue_ But there is now WorkBench V8.0.19

Comment: @GoeGilber Why do you need another option? I deleted my mistaken comment saying that it doesn't exist in MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar  I didnt notice
I have tried not putting the view name in single quotes but it still doesnt work

Comment: You already said that.